# Data Binding a DataGrid to an Object with Nested Classes

Tags: c#, json, wpf, xaml, datagrid

So I have an api call that runs a query and returns a JSON response.  Because of the structure of the JSON response I have created a class that I can use Json.Net to Deserialize the return straight into.  Here is the example class:

```
public class QuerySet
{
    public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }
    public class Column
    {
        public List<string> Name { get; set; }
    }
    public List<RowSet> Rows { get; set; }
    public class RowSet
    {
        public List<DataSet> Row { get; set; }
        public class DataSet
        {
            public List<string> Data { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, a single API call can contain several query sets, so for each return, I generate a list of query sets, that I then want to data bind a DataGrid to each set.  Here is an example of what I have so far in the code behind my window:

```
    public List<DataGrid> QueryResults;

    public QueryResultsWindow(string _name, JObject _returns)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        QueryNameText.Text = _name;
        QueryResults = new List<DataGrid>();

        JArray sets = (JArray)_returns.SelectToken("$..Set");

        foreach(JObject set in sets)
        {
            DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
            QuerySet s = new QuerySet();
            s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuerySet>(set.ToString());

            dg.ItemsSource = s.Rows;

            QueryResults.Add(dg);
        }

        ResultsListBox.ItemsSource = QueryResults;
    }
```

The issue here as you might see is that for each particular DataGrid, I want the Column Headers bound to the Name property, and the data populated from the Data properties.

Here is how I currently have the XAML setup in the window:

```
   <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock x:Name="QueryNameText" Margin="5"></TextBlock>
            <Button Content="Export Results" Click="Button_Click" Margin="5"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" Name="ResultsListBox">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionUnit="Cell">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </DockPanel>
```

I know that if I wanted to create a custom class for each possible return type, this would be much easier.  However, given the hundreds of potential return types, this does not seem very feasible.  I've tried using DataTables, I've tried setting the DataGrid in the ListBox in XAML, but I may not have implemented this correctly, and finally came to the resolution of trying to create a list of DataGrids and then binding to those.

I could use some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO after some messing around with this.  Here is the answer I came up with.

I took the query set class above and added a method to build a DataTable inside the QuerySet Class:

```
   public class QuerySet
    {
        public DataTable BindableTable { get; private set; }
        public static List<string> ColumnName { get; private set; }
        public static List<RowSet.DataSet> RowsSet { get; private set; }

        public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }
        public class Column
        {
            private List<string> _name;

            public List<string> Name
            {
                get { return _name; }
                set { _name = value; ColumnName = _name; }
            }


        }
        public List<RowSet> Rows { get; set; }

        public class RowSet
        {
            private List<DataSet> _row;

            public List<DataSet> Row
            {
                get { return _row; }
                set { _row = value; RowsSet = _row; }
            }

            public class DataSet
            {
                public List<string> Data { get; set; }
            }
        }

        public void GetDataGridTable()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            foreach(string name in ColumnName)
            {
                table.Columns.Add(name);
            }
            foreach(RowSet.DataSet set in RowsSet)
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                int counter = 0;
                foreach(string item in set.Data)
                {
                    row[counter] = item;
                    counter++;
                }
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            BindableTable = table;
        }
    }
```

I added a couple of accessors to make getting to the nested bits easier, and built a DataTable from there.  In my code behind my popup window, I created an Observable Collection of DataGrids, and set the DataContext of each Grid to a DataView based on the QuerySet:

```
    public ObservableCollection<DataGrid> QueryResults;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public QueryResultsWindow(string _name, JObject _returns)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        QueryNameText.Text = _name;
        QueryResults = new ObservableCollection<DataGrid>();

        JArray sets = (JArray)_returns.SelectToken("$..Set");

        foreach(JObject set in sets)
        {
            DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
            QuerySet s = new QuerySet();
            s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QuerySet>(set.ToString());

            s.GetDataGridTable();
            DataView newView = new DataView(s.BindableTable);
            dg.ItemsSource = newView;
            dg.CanUserAddRows = false;
            dg.CanUserDeleteRows = false;
            QueryResults.Add(dg);
        }

        ResultsListBox.ItemsSource = QueryResults;
    }
```

Then the XAML inside my popup window was pretty straight forward:

```
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock x:Name="QueryNameText" Margin="5"></TextBlock>
        <Button Content="Export Results" Click="Button_Click" Margin="5"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" Name="ResultsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding QueryResults}">
    </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

Obviously this is not the most elegant solution.  Even just looking at it here I could easily create the DataView in the QuerySet class rather than doing that conversion in the code behind.  So, while the answer isn't perfect, it's working for now.